# SqlConnection Data Source , need to be changed when working on different PC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\mr\\Desktop\\ment Final\\ment Final\\App_Data\\LoginStuff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

So every time I run the project on new PC I have to change all the Data sources again and again . is there any to avoid that ?

Comment: Haven't you heard of configuration files?

Answer (score 4):

Instead use connection strings and the web.config for easing changes.

web.config example:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="LoginDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\mr\\Desktop\\ment Final\\ment Final\\App_Data\\LoginStuff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Change your code to:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDB"].ConnectionString);
```

You likely already have a web.config in the root of your project and you can simply add this connectionStrings section or just add this new connection string if the section already exists!

Answer (score 0):

Use config file. Can be found in root of the project as web.config in ASP.NET and app.config in class and windows project

```
<connectionString>
 <add 
     name="connStr" 
     connectionstring="Server=myServerAddress;
                       Database=myDataBase;
                       Trusted_Connection=True;"
 </connectionString>
```

In cs

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what Amit and Subterfuge said above, your connection string should be stored in a configuration file instead of in the code. Those methods won't solve the face that you would still need to modify the connection string on every machine though. Instead, I recommend you create a convention for local development and use configuration transforms between development/staging/production environments.

**Local Development Convention**
It will be easiest to develop against your code locally if you put the database in the same location on every machine. The .NET convention is to use the [app_data folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) in your project's root folder. If you place your database in this folder on each machine you're developing on then you won't need to change the connection string.

For example, copy LoginStuff.mdf into your project's /app_data folder (create the folder if it doesn't exist). Change your connection string to:

```
<connectionString>
    <add name="loginStuff" connectionstring="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|LoginStuff.mdf;User Instance=true"
</connectionString>
```

Then in code you can reference it by adding a using to System.Configuration and then referencing the connection string:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["loginStuff"].ConnectionString);
```

**Between Environments**
Between environments (debug, release, etc) you can use [configuration transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx%20configuration%20transforms) to modify the web.config automatically. For each environment you need to create a web.{environment}.config file in your project's root directory. Use XML transformations to specify how you want to modify your configuration file.

These should cover your two most common scenarios. Cheers!

Comment: I've actually seen a better solution that we use here at work, it involves grabbing the Environment.MachineName and seeing whether there is a connection string with the format of say... "LoginDB-MyComputerName".  Makes dev environments very portable when working on teams since everyone can keep their own connection string without breaking versioning.  Maybe I'll create a new answer when I have more time.

Comment: Both methods are valid and include positives and negatives. Using convention works fine as long as the machine name matches, which it probably won't in a cluster. Configuration transforms are verbose and easy for some tools to modify easier. The user likely isn't running a dedicated SQL instance and could easier reference things by relative path.